# Feasibility of a wind-up radio?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, radio

I am wondering about the feasibility of a wind-up radio, meaning a tactical radio transceiver with 2-watt and 5-watt settings that would be powered by a rechargeable battery attached to a dynamo so it could be recharged by turning a crank. How much talk time would you get per minute of cranking? About how long would it take to recharge a typical handset battery to full from empty?

This is relevant because in a lot of war zones there is no regular power and disposal batteries may be hard to come by.

I am looking for estimates and ball park figures for a typical design figures of merit.

Comment: How much electrical power do you get from your hypothetical crank dynamo while cranking?

Comment: Depends on the power of "cranking". I.e. the "resistance" (gear ratio / generator power / electrical load, resulting in the mechanical resistance) and the speed. And these can vary *very much* between different persons.

Comment: You have to ask the biology guys how much mechanical energy someone could produce in one minute. And mechanical engineering about the losses of the gear. From electrical point, losses in such a simple generator are about  5-10%.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After doing some more research on this, I found that hand cranked tactical radios are a well-known thing and that among others [Barrett makes hand cranking systems](http://www.barrettcommunications.com.au/tactical/HF_power.html). These are not small systems though and the hand crank is more for a base station situation.

Midland used to make a hand cranked survival radio called "Basecamp", which is a 5 watt system:

[image]

Users say that you have to crank it for about 2 minutes to get an hours use.

Comment: Users then definitely didn't use it to transmit 5W. Energy conservation wouldn't allow that. even without any losses (and those should be >70%), for an hour of 5W being generated in 2 minutes, whoever cranks it must have generated 150W. Unless you're a professional rower… see Uwe's answer.

Comment: Also that whole thing looks very flimsy. let that crank be 10cm long (it's clearly shorter), and let's assume you'd do 1 rotation per second – then the torque 
$$\tau = \frac{P}{\omega}=\frac{150\,\frac{\text J }{\text{s}}}{2\pi\,\text{Hz}}\approx  25 \,\text{Nm}$$

Comment: So, don't ask a question, then get two good answers, and then ignore one of them and find a seller who's willing to lie to you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 5W is peak transmit power. I am sure most users spent most of their time listening, not talking. Also, 1 hour of "use", just means the machine is turned on, not that it is transmitting or receiving. In other words use is being able to receive a transmission, should it occur.

Comment: Then, get something with a battery that lasts forever.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the [Gibson Girls](http://www.wftw.nl/gibsongirl.html) aka the USA SCR-578.

[image]

The name came, in less politically correct days, from the "waist" in the case, allowing the operator to hold the generator between his knees while cranking it. (Image from above link, actually shows the German equivalent)

Effective radiated powers of 6 to 8 Watts are mentioned in the article, consistent with your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

How much power may be generated by cranking? It depends on several points: Using both arms or only one, a small crank or a stable, large aparatus, the fitness of the operator, the duration of cranking and the effort of the operator.

I could generate 150 W using my legs with medium effort and about 200 W for ten minutes and high effort. Using both arms, I was able to do 50 W. But 50 W with the arms required more effort than 150 W using the legs.

I would guess 3 to 10 W using one arm and a small aparatus and 25 to 75 W using both arms and a large and heavy crank generator.

If you want to experience it personally what effort is necessary to crank 5, 10, 25 or 50 W, look for a training apparatus used in rehabilitaion centers and try it yourself.